# Is there an R function to re-evaluate the classes of the columns of a data frame?

Tags: r

I'm reading in an XML file and then converting it to a data frame (sparse). For the conversion I'm using the package XML and the function xmlToDataFrame. Almost all columns have multiple NA's as elements but the values I do have can be logical or numeric. When I do the conversion all column classes come out as characters. Is there anyway to make R re-evaluate the classes of the columns such that it will then automatically attach "numeric" to the correct column instead of "character"?

I do not believe the NA's are at fault as in a small test case I can feed R a vector with NA's and numbers and it will automatically be classified as "numeric". I can also define them into the correct class by hand. For what it is worth, if I call unique I get back things like 
(NA, 9, 9.00, 9.00000).

There are too many columns to fix by hand and would really like this automated if possible. Thank you!

Comment: `type.convert`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes! I didn't know that function existed/couldn't find it. Thank you!

Comment: happy to help... `base` has many hidden corners to be discovered :)